# How can I listing only certain emails in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

So I have at table in SQL and I want to list only people who have an email at yahoo.com

for example:

```
EMAIL
------------
1234@yahoo.com
djasjdkl@gmail.com
414353@yahoo.com
12345@gmail.com
78923@msn.com
390214@yahoo.com
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what database you're using, but something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE email LIKE "%@yahoo.com"
```

Where `people` is your table name and `email` the column with the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where email like '%@yahoo.com'
```

Comment: You're missing the 't' in `select`